# Crop images with two borders

Tags: image-processing, image

I often download images with two borders (frame and mat). Here is an example downloaded from [link](https://whitney.org/collection/works/11590):

[image]

```
img = Import["mydirectory/" <> "man ray 1924.jpeg"]
```

Not having much experience with Mathematica's image processing features I thought that cropping twice would remove the two borders:

```
ImageCrop @ ImageCrop @ img
```

[image]

But the second `ImageCrop` doesn't change anything - only the frame is removed.

Doing the cropping manually (which is cumbersome) gives

```
ImageTake[img, {60, 350}, {65, 290}]
```

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to get the above result automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAlmj.jpg"];
ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[GradientFilter[img, 1], 0.1]]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- Since there are some letters on the right down corner,the crop seems not so perfect.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAlmj.jpg"];
dim = Information[ImageCrop@ColorNegate@Binarize@img][
  "ImageDimensions"]
ImageCrop[img, dim]
```

[image]

- The method by @Domen in the comment.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAlmj.jpg"];
{dim1, dim2} = 
 BorderDimensions[
  ColorNegate@Binarize@img]; ImageTake[img, {-1, 1}  dim2 // 
  Reverse, {-1, 1}  dim1 // Reverse]
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work properly not due to the letters in the right-down corner, but because using only "ImageDimensions", you are cropping _symmetrically_ from all borders. Instead, try something like `{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = BorderDimensions[ColorNegate@Binarize@img];
ImageTake[img, {y2, -y1}, {x2, -x1}]`

Comment: @Domen  Thanks, such method work fine.